# iniciar com o 9 na frente com jquery

Tags: jquery, html5

Tenho esse código que me da a mascara do telefone, porém não consigo fazer com que o input já inicie com o 9 na frente, impedindo que o usuário consiga apagá-lo, tornando-o obrigatório. Alguém tem ideia que como fazer?

```
<script>
    if (opt == "Celular") {
        if (document.getElementById('fone').readOnly)
            document.getElementById('fone').readOnly = false;

        mask = "99999-9999";
        document.getElementById("oc_oc").className = "oculto";
    }
</script>

<div class="num_class">
    <label>Numero</label><br>
    <input readonly maxlength="10" required class="inp_editar" type="text" name="fone_tel" id="fone"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer algo parecido com isso

```
$("input").keydown(function(e) {
    var oldvalue=$(this).val();
    var field=this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if(field.value.indexOf('9') !== 0) {
            $(field).val(oldvalue);
        } 
    }, 1);
});
```

[Aqui um exemplo funcionando](http://jsfiddle.net/J2BKU/876/)

Utilizei o jquery que pode ser [baixado aqui](https://jquery.com/download/)

`subistitua input por #seuId ou .suaClas`

Comment: No meu caso não funcionou, pois interfere com a primeira função, obrigado!